# Using clipboard.js how to destroy all its object before creating new one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, clipboard.js

Using clipboard something like this in my controller

```
function myController() {
    new Clipboard('.btn', {
        text: function(trigger) { return 'some dynamic text'; }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is everytime the controller is loaded, it creates a new object of Clipboard, is there any way I can destroy all its objects before creating new?
here is the link to library: https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/

Comment: documentation clearly says on the end var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn'); clipboard.destroy();

Comment: cannot do it inside controller, as whenever controller I will not have any reference to var clipboard created previously.

Answer (score 4):

Just save the instance of the clipboard and erase the previous one:

```
var previousClipboard = null;

function myController() {
    if(previousClipboard != null){
        previousClipboard.destroy();
    }
    previousClipboard = new Clipboard('.btn', {
        text: function(trigger) { return 'some dynamic text'; }
    }
}
```